# configurar posição do botão "search cancel" num input type=search no Safari 7

Tags: html, css, safari

Tenho um `input[type=search]` com `padding`. Como quero ter o mesmo estilo em browsers diferentes usei `-webkit-appearance: none;` mas no Safari 7 (mavericks pelo menos) O botão que faz reset/cancel da busca fica cortado. Como posso corrigir isto?

Tenho estado a tentar com o seletor `::-webkit-search-cancel-button` que funciona por exemplo para o econder (`display: none;`) mas não o consigo mudar mais para a esquerda...

Sugestões?

[image]

**jsFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/hjtkarLc/**

O setup do jsFiddle:

CSS

```
input {
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    margin: 1em;
}
input[type="search"] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
#withPadding {
    padding: 0.7em;
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="search" value="I'm ok" />
<input type="search" id="withPadding" value="I'm cutoff" />
```

<sub>[Coloquei a mesma pergunta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26689356/2256325)</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilize o `::-webkit-search-cancel-button`, transforme a posição dele em absoluto, `position:absolute` e realize o alinhamento com o `right`.

Para ter a posição dele dentro do `input`, defina a posição do elemento como relativo, `position:relative` e determine o limite do texto dentro do `input` com o `padding-right`.

```css
input {
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    margin: 1em;
}
input[type="search"] {
    position:relative;
    padding-right: 30px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

/* saf3+, chrome1+ */
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {

    input[type="search"] {
        position:relative;
        padding-right: 30px;
    }

    ::-webkit-search-cancel-button {   
        right: 10px;
        position:absolute;
    }
}
 
   
#withPadding {
    padding: 0.7em;
}
```

```html
<input type="search" value="I'm ok" />
<input type="search" id="withPadding" value="I'm cutoff" />
```

Comment: Muito interessante! Curiosamente quando carrego no `x` vejo que o cursor não muda para carregar, como se a imagem e a zona do ecrã que aceita clic na `x` está desfazada. Mas ajustando para `right: 0px;` [funcionou bem](http://jsfiddle.net/te0y9ot6/). Obrigado!